# PhpStorm: MySQL execution time format

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, duration

When I run a MySQL query via console I get the execution time in a rational format like this :

```
25 row(s) retrieved starting from 0 in 33/332 ms
```

I can't understand this message.

How can I get this value as a decimal number ?

Comment: what do you want to get in a decimal value ?

Comment: execution time , instead of 33/332 ms i prefer xx.yy ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it now
33 is fetch time
and 332 is execution time in ms